# treat 0x00 as NULL

Tags: postgresql, file, null

I have a large file (over 1gb) containing lots of music data, and I want to read this file using the COPY command. It is one large table. with a lot of tracks.

However, at row 372032 there are a few tracks that have no genre, but a 0x00 character instead. After some googling I found out the 0x00 character is a NULL symbol, but postgresql is having problems reading this.

What I would like is that postgresql treats 0x00 as NULL. Looking at the [postgresql documentation for COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html), and saw the copy command has an option for reading specific strings as NULL. I tried this, but couldn't get it by adding the option NULL '\0x00' (I also tried '\x00', '0x00', 'x00'). I think this is because postgresql first wants to be able to read something, before it can replace.

I ran the following script

```
COPY music
FROM 'mw_spotify_labels.csv'
WITH DELIMITER '    '
NULL '\0x00'
encoding 'latin1';
```

This gives me the following error message

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "LATIN1": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY music, line 372032
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "LATIN1": 0x00
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY music, line 372032
```

I tried using a few different encodings (did not work). I also tried [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) that replaces 0x00 with a space, but I couldn't find a nice way to define 0x00.

Does anybody know a way to either get the NULL working, setting up a replace 0x00 with ' ' or an other solution that makes it possible for me to import this file?

Comment: As far as I understand, CSV format doesn't support NULLs internally, so 0x00 character is definitely something invalid. I'd replace all 0x00 characters with \N or <NULL> or some other placeholder. The problem currently is not in executing query or properly handling nulls - PostgreSQL basically can't read and parse your corrupted CSV file.

Comment: may be you should try another encoding , like  `psql=# copy tmp from '/path/to/file.csv' with delimiter ',' csv header encoding 'windows-1251';`

Comment: in my case the solution was remove 0x00 from file (in linux it's simple)  tr < in.csv -d '\000' > out.csv

Answer (score 1):

Edit file by Vim, and replace all `\0x00` to `''`. That works.

```
:%s/\%x00//g
```